Android socket.io, node.js as server, android as client
here is a nodejs server code snippet that works fine :
const express = require("express")
const { createServer } = require("node:http")
const { Server } = require("socket.io")

const app = express()
const server = createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server)

app.get("/",function(req,res) {
    res.send("<h1>Hello</h1>")
})

io.on("connection",function(socket) {
   console.log("connected")
   socket.on("disconnect",function(msg) {
      console.log("user disconnected",msg);
   });
})

server.listen(4000,"127.0.0.1",function() {
   console.log("listen 4000")
})

here is the nodejs client code snipped that works fine :

const { io } = require("socket.io-client");

const socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:4000")

socket.on("connect",function() {
   console.log(socket.connected)
  const engine = socket.io.engine;
  console.log(engine.transport.name);
})


here is the Android java client code snippet that doesn't connect to server process :
    package fr.albisys.testio;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
    import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
    import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

    import io.socket.client.IO;
    import io.socket.client.Socket;
    import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

    import java.net.URISyntaxException;

    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.text.TextUtils;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private EditText mview;

        private Socket iosocket;

        {
            Log.v("act","IO begin");
            try {
                iosocket = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:4000");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                Log.v("act","URI not good");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.v("act","IO later");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.v("activity","oncreate");
            EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
                Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
                v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
                return insets;
            });
            Log.v("activity","onrecv");
            iosocket.on("message", recvMessage);
            Log.v("activity","connect");
            iosocket.connect();
            Log.v("activity","emit");
            iosocket.emit("message","message");
            Log.v("activity","emited");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.v("activity","deco");
            iosocket.disconnect();
            Log.v("activity","onfinish");
            iosocket.off("finish", recvMessage);
        }

        private void sendMessage() {
            String message = mview.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                Log.v("sendMsg","empty");
                return;
            }
            mview.setText("");
            iosocket.emit("message", message);
        }
        private Emitter.Listener recvMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.v("activity","received");
                        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                        String message;
                        try {
                            message = data.getString("message");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return;
                        }
                        Log.v("activity",message);
                        mview.setText(message);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

I did not succeed to connect android client to the server.
I used mostly samples and tutos.
The code goes all the way oncreate, the server never get connected
Thanks
At some point I had a problem because one was an localhost IPv6 and the other was IPv4. I figure the problem and forced IP to be localhost 127.0.0.1 explicitely.
Now my problem is that the server never reaches connection state :
io.on("connection",function(socket) {
   console.log("connected")
})

Below is the libs.versions.toml file
  [versions]
  agp = "8.4.0"
  junit = "4.13.2"
  junitVersion = "1.1.5"
  espressoCore = "3.5.1"
  appcompat = "1.7.0"
  material = "1.12.0"
  activity = "1.9.0"
  constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
  okhttp = "5.0.0-alpha.14"
  socketIoClient = "2.1.0"


[libraries]
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
ext-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
okhttp = { group = "com.squareup.okhttp3", name = "okhttp", version.ref = "okhttp" }
socket-io-client = { group = "io.socket", name = "socket.io-client", version.ref = "socketIoClient" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }

My laptop is where I run the node server as 127.0.0.1.
My Samsung mobile phone runs the java client, connected to the laptop using USB C cable, not connected to Wifi nor 4G.
*Solved the problem by connecting the mobile and laptop on the same wifi network. I had a bad understanding of the network in debug mode
Thanks for your help @ Morrison Chang


What if any messages/errors are in the logcat? 2) Where are you running the Android client code (device or emulator). Note your server address of 127.0.0.1 in Android points back to Android, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses


The run goes fine to the "edited" client console message but we never see the "connected" console message on the server side. I know the server works well with a nodejs client

The client executes on a recent samsung mobile phone ( via adb ) not the emulator, the editText takes the default value as expected.

Can you edit your post to include which library dependency via gradle you are importing for Android and which version of socket.io you are running.

@Chang sorry I don't know if it's right, I changed the client code :  iosocket = IO.socket("http://10.0.2.2:4000/");    instead of 127.0.0.1 .   it's not better

In the Android client, if you are running in emulator on same PC as node.js server use address "10.0.2.2". If you are running Android client on physical device you need to use your local PC ip address. If you are still having problems then it is a network issue (port blocking perhaps?)
